# How can I remove first array from PDO fetchAll()?

Tags: php, pdo

So I'm trying to do a login system but, I have a problem.

I'm using `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` function to retrieve user's data from database and as expected, returns this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => Berk
            [password] => $2y$12$.TDZWwCFfBkM.uVdUkwrVODWu6Nt8QsWMWOFXnOTFQ5CHw57pa1Cu
            [discord] => Berkay#1603
            [likes] => 5
            [role] => Developer
            [avatar] => 
            [region] => Global
        )

)
```

My code:

```
if($requestType == 'login')
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $user = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :u");
    $user->bindParam(':u', $username);
    $user->execute();
    if($user->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        $user->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $user = $user->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print_r($user);
        if(password_verify($password,$user[0]['password']))
        {
            // Logged in 
            foreach($user as $key => $value)
            {
                    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
                    print_r($_SESSION);
            }
    }
    }

}
```

And my question is, how can I remove the first array where only return is `0`?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove `All` from `fetchAll`, kudos for using prepared queries and hashed passwords.

Comment: Thanks! it worked, didn't know it was that easy to be honest.